# Continue a Civ5 game over internet that started on LAN

Tags: civilization-5

Is it possible to start a multiplayer game of Civ 5 on a LAN connection, save the game in progress, and then at a later point, continue the game over the internet? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Are you saying you want to have some players connect via LAN and some players connect over the Internet?

Comment: I do not know the answer to the first part so I will post here instead. Private rooms work by putting a password that your friend will need to know to get in to the room. Once he is in you can add as many AI as you want to fill out the rest of the players.

Answer (score 2):

After every turn, the game is saved automatically. After you stop playing on a LAN game, you can normally restart by loading the saved game (which takes you to the lobby, so all the players can join again (or be replaced by AI if they don't want to join again)).

I imagine the process would be similar online.